# Integrar leitor de QRCode no sistema Delphi!

Tags: delphi

Gostaria de saber se é possivel integrar ao delphi um leitor de QRCode que use a WebCam para efetuar a leitura. Ou um leitor de codigo de barras. Não tenho nem idéia de como começar, por isso não fiz nada ainda!

Comment: Como eu não vou ter tempo de redigir uma resposta, veja esse link: http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/qr_codes_delphi.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tanto os leitores simples quanto os mais complexos utilizam a entrada do teclado ou usb para imputar os dados no seu sistema.

Para ler `QRCode` costuma-se utilizar [um leitor 2d](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=leitor%20de%20c%C3%B3digo%20de%20barras&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:pt-BR:official&client=firefox-a&gfe_rd=cr&ei=XYOHU7qSLciU8Qf3nYCYAQ#q=leitor%20de%20c%C3%B3digo%20de%20barras%202d&rls=org.mozilla:pt-BR:official). Este imputa no campo com foco a string do `QRCode`*(ou o tipo de código 2d que for)* e por default envia uma quebra de linha ao final.

Na programação nada muda, vai ser como se o usuário tivesse digitado o código e apertado enter. Por exemplo:

Lendo este QRCode:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com o leitor 2d, você vai adicionar `12345678901234567890` no campo com foco.